# Bounded and invertible operator on dense subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Who can give me an operator like this or show it doesn't exist: Operator T: X-->Y, is a bijection from normed linear space X to normed linear space Y. X, Y are equipped with the same norm, and X is a proper dense subset of Y. Both T and inverse of T are bounded.

Comment: What about the identity with $X=Y$? Well, you say, $T$ is a 'bijection', do you mean, *onto* $Y$?

Comment: Thank you for your response. X should be a real subspace of Y. Bijection means one-to-one and onto.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "$X$ is contained and dense in $Y$." Do you mean via some *other* map $S : X \to Y$?

Comment: I mean X is a dense subset of Y. No other mappings.

Comment: There is no such $T$ if $Y$ is a Banach space.

Comment: Sure. So Y should not be Banach.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $X = Y$ and $T$ be the Fourier transform on the Schwartz space of functions. If $X = Y$, it is trivially dense in Y and the Fourier transform is bounded on the Schwartz space with the $L^2$ norm (and so is its inverse).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I add some restriction to my question, and now X,Y should not be equal.

Comment: Do you want the extension of $T$ to all of $Y$ to be bijective or not?

Comment: I mean T is already a bijection from X onto Y, need not to be extended.